# TCL clock command GMT?

Tags: tcl

I have a TCL script that extracts various date and time formats from text files (.eml files), and then formats them with a consistant naming convention (in this case YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS). I'm using the clock command to scan the string containing the date+time data (ie $edate), but get this error with GMT numbers

> unable to convert date-time string "Wed, 20 Jan 1999 00:16:51 +1030": syntax error (characters 31-31)

The TCL command is simply

```
set efilename [clock format [clock scan $edate] -format {%Y%m%d_%H%M%S}]
```

In a loop, $edate contains various date time formats - eg

"Tue, 21 Apr 1998 15:17:09 CST"

"3/18/99 8:58:22 PM Pacific Daylight Time"

"Thu, 3 Dec 1998 12:56:18 +1030"

"27/04/1999 12:04:04 PM Australian Eastern Daylight Time"

"21 Mar 1998 9:13:12 AM AEST"

"4 January 1999 21:00:02 WDT"

"Sun, 14 Dec 97 00:41:02 -00800 (PST)"

...etc...

Clearly clock doesn't like the GMT in the $edata string, nor does it like the full text for the timzone (only accepts the code "PST", "CST" etc.).

Is there a way to get around the clock command limitation of recognizing the timezone with the [clock scan ....] command?

Comment: `clock scan` without a `-format` argument is deprecated. Start by coming up with formats for all the possible date/time formats you need to handle...

Comment: And see https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm#M78 for details of how the time zone format field is parsed.

Comment: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm#M78 does not include all the timezones

Comment: Note that some timezone abbreviations are ambiguous; parsing timezone names is *very hard*. That's why `:Continent/City` form is more commonly used in computing circles (and is what the common timezone database promotes).

Comment: EEST, ZP4, ZP5 & ZP6 fail, but these work (regsub): UTC +0000, WET +0000, WAT +0100, AT +0200, NDT +0230, ADT +0300, NFT +0330, NST +0330, AST +0400, EDT +0400, EST +0500, CDT +0500, CST +0600, MDT +0600, MST +0700, PST +0800, YDT +0800, YST +0900, HDT +0900, HST +1000, CAT +1000, AHST +1000, NT +1100, IDLW +1200, BST -0100, CET -0100, MET -0100, MEWT -0100, SWT -0100, CEST -0200, MEST -0200, SST -0200, EET -0200, BT -0300, IT -0330, IST -0530, WAST -0700, JT -0730, CCT -0800, JST -0900, CAST -0930 
CADT -1030, EAST -1000, GST -1000, EADT -1100, NZT -1200, NZST -1200, IDLE -1200, NZDT -1300